# Filter rows by multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have:

```
user_id    log_category    session_num
1 Rob      user            1
2 Fred     progression     2
3 Rob      design          1
4 Mike     user            1
5 Fred     user            2
6 Fred     progression     1
```

I need to stay all rows from users that have row with `log_category == user` and(not or) `session_num == 1`

Desired output:

```
user_id    log_category    session_num
1 Rob        user            1
2 Rob        design          1
3 Mike       user            1
```

Comment: @mtoto You don't get it right! I need ALL LOGS from users who have log log_category == user and session_num == 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could extract the users who meet the conditions, and subsequently use it to subset the data.

```
# Extract users
users <- df$user_id[df$session_num==1 & df$log_category == "user"]

# Subset data
df[df$user_id %in% users,]
#   user_id log_category session_num
#1      Rob         user           1
#2      Rob       design           1
#3     Mike         user           1
```